# Clarification on adding Objective C code to a swift dynamic framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, frameworks

I have a dynamic framework in swift that currently is linking in another framework that is written in Objective C.  This works but its annoying because the Objective C framework really only 2 files and I was wondering if there is a way to bring this into my swift framework.

If this was an application I'd user **Bridging-Header** but that is not supported inside a swift framework.

My framework is called **GDL90** and consists of only swift files.

My Objective-C framework consists of:

- `GeoidCalculator.h`
- `GeoidCalculator.m`
- `EGM96` (data file)
- `CORCOEF`(data file)

Real simple - right?  So I wanted to see if there was a way to just add this code into my swift project.

#### Attempt #1 - add my code into the "umbrella header?" `GDL90.h`

I added my file an get the warning **Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'GDL90'**

Ok so thats no dice.

#### Attempt 2

I figured I needed to make a module map file.

So I made a directory called `${SRCROOT}/GDL90/EGM96` and inside I created `EGM96.module.modulemap`

```
module EGM96 {
    header "GeoidCalculator.h"
    export *
}
```

And then in one of my swift files i have `import EGM96` which doesn't seem to be found.

In my build settings i have:

`Define Modules` turned on and I'm pointing to the `modulemap` file from my **Module Map File** item

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the modulemap files if create internal framework correctly:

1. Create new framework target “EGM96” under EGM96 project:

   - go to GDL90 Project -> Add New Target -> Cocoa Touch Framework
   - input the Name and select Objective-C as language
     [image]
2. Add objective-с files and other sources of EGM96 to new target.
   [image]
3. Add GeoidCalculator.h as public header:

   - Change target membership of GeoidCalculator.h header from “Project” to “Public”
     [image]
   - Import headers to the umbrella file called EGM96.h
   - Make sure umbrella header EGM96.h is public for EGM96 target.
     [image]
4. Add new framework to target dependence of GDL90 and add new library to linked binaries of GDL90.
   [image]
5. Now you can import EGM96 in any swift file of EGM96:

`import EGM96`