# Trying to integrate C++ code into a Swift framework project with XCode - fails

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to integrate C++ code (fuzzylite.com) into a Swift framework project and I keep receiving build errors. From what I understand, you cannot use a bridging header in Swift framework projects, rather you need to include the source in the Umbrella headers. I wrapped the C++ code in Objective-C classes and then included the Objective-C headers in the umbrella header as such:

```
#import <Fuzzylite/ObjCWrapper.h>
```

Followed all the steps as mentioned here ([Clarification on adding Objective C code to a swift dynamic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773349/clarification-on-adding-objective-c-code-to-a-swift-dynamic-framework)) but it doesn't really work because it is not able to find the Objective-C wrapped C++ framework. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by doing the following:

1. Added C++ source directory into XCode project
2. Expose C function wrappers to C++ instance methods
3. Created C header file wrapper for the C++ project like such:

   ```
   #ifndef Header_h
   #define Header_h
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
   #endif
   void hello(char *str);  
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   }
   #endif
   #endif /* Header_h */
   ```
4. In the Umbrella header file (in my case the name of the Umbrella header file was 'TestSDK.h') for the framework project (remember that since this was a framework target, there was no bridging header involved as is the case when building an app), I put the following.:

   ```
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   #import "fuzzylite/fl/Headers.h"
   #endif
   ```
5. Added the -I/ to XCode->Target->Build Settings->Other C Flags. In my case, the path was:

   ```
   -I$(PROJECT_DIR)/TestSDK/fuzzylite/
   ```

This worked for me. Without step 5, I was getting path include errors.

Comment: I am trying to do same thing but my extern "C" functions if not declared giving undefined symbol error.

Comment: @abhi change your .h file to .hpp